# How do I uncompress an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm running out of ideas on how to uncompress an array (request array A[] to response array B[])

Here are my definitions

**A** is a request class.

```
class A
{
   public string Date { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my array of requests of class A with its initalization.

```
var request = new A[]
  {
      new A { Date = "14-04-2016", Price = 100 },
      new A { Date = "15-04-2016", Price = 100 },
      new A { Date = "16-04-2016", Price = 0 },
      new A { Date = "17-04-2016", Price = 100 },
      new A { Date = "18-04-2016", Price = 100 }
  };
```

**B** is a respond class.

```
class B
{
   public string Start { get; set; }
   public string End { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The above requests needs to be converted to an array of `B`. Something like this

```
var response = new B[]
  {
      new B { Start = "14-04-2016", End = "16-04-2016", Price = 100 },
      new B { Start = "16-04-2016", End = "17-04-2016", Price = 0 },
      new B { Start = "17-04-2016", End = "18-04-2016", Price = 100 }
  };
```

The response is grouped based on the Price and order by date. Its more of like, I need to uncompress the request array A[] into response array B[].

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `GroupBy` linq extension, following query returns `List<B>`objects.

```
var results = request.Select(s=> 
           new 
           {
               Price = s.Price, 
               Date = DateTime.ParseExact(s.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy", null) // convert to Date.
           })
   .GroupBy(g=>g.Price)
   .Select(s=>
           new B() 
           {
               Start = s.Min(c=>c.Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
               End = s.Max(c=>c.Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
               Price = s.Key   
           })
   .ToList() ;
```

**Update :**

As per comments, you don't really require grouping on price. What you need is grouping *adjacent* items whose price is matching .

We could achieve this with slight modification to above `Linq` query.

```
    int grp = 0;
    decimal prevprice=response.First().Price;
    var results = request.Select((s, i)=> 
                  {

                      grp = s.Price == prevprice? grp : ++grp;                       
                      prevprice = s.Price;
                       return new 
                       {
                           grp,
                           Price = s.Price, 
                           Date = DateTime.ParseExact(s.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy", null)
                       };
                  })
           .GroupBy(g=>g.grp)
           .Select(s=>
                   new B() 
                   {
                       Start = s.Min(c=>c.Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                       End = s.Max(c=>c.Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                       Price = s.First().Price   
                   });
```

**Output**

```
14-04-2016,15-04-2016 ,100 
16-04-2016,16-04-2016 ,0 
17-04-2016,18-04-2016 ,100
```

Working [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KPiNdN)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But your implementation yields me like this `14-04-2016,18-04-2016,100`,`16-04-2016,16-04-2016,0`, which is not my preferred output.

Comment: What is your preferred output? Question was about converting `A `type to `B` type. Am I missing something?

Comment: Preferred output is the one which I had shown in `response` array which is in the question details.

Comment: It is the samething, probably only thing you can modify is `ToList()` to `ToArray()` as you need an array.

Comment: Nope. Something like this `14-04-2016, 16-04-2016, 100` , `16-04-2016, 17-04-2016, 0`, `17-04-2016, 18-04-2016, 100` and not like `14-04-2016, 18-04-2016, 100`, `16-04-2016, 16-04-2016, 0`

Comment: I'm glad it worked to you. Please vote and mark as an answer if it solved your problem and is the solution to the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode (assumes request is ordered by date - if not you can sort it easily):

```
int lastPrice = -1;

//count the distinct price ranges
int responseSize = 0;
foreach (A requestObj in request) {
 if (requestObj.price != lastPrice) {
  responseSize++;
  lastPrice = requestObj.price;
 }
}


//set the initial element
B[] response = new B[responseSize];
response[0].start = request[0].date;
response[0].price = request[0].price;
int responseindex = 0;

//parse the result
foreach (A requestObj in request) {
 if (requestObj.price != response[responseindex].price) {
  response[responseindex].end = requestObj.date;
  responseIndex++;
  response[responseindex].price = requestObj.price;
  response[responseindex].start= requestObj.date;
 }
}

//set the end date of the final object
response[response.length - 1].end = request[request.length - 1].date;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with the following:

```
var response = from reqItem in request
group reqItem by reqItem.Price into g
select new B()
{ 
    Start = g.Min(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Date)).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
    End = g.Max(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Date)).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
    Price = g.Key
};
```